Can a Microsoft-Hosted Agent deploy Databricks using the Databricks Asset Bundle?
Is there anyway to deploy Databricks which has Public Access disabled (Workspace can only be accessed using Private Endpoint - databricks_ui_api endpoint) using a MS-hosted agent ?
I use Azure Devops Pipeline to deploy Databricks Workspace using DBAs. When using Self-Host agent, I can deploy successfully. However, when using Microsoft-host agent, I cannot deploy. I think because Workspace is private, can only be accessed by Private Endpoint, so I cannot use Microsoft-host agent.
I don't have any solution yet.

I am afraid that you cannot deploy Databricks using a Microsoft-host agent when the Workspace has Public Access disabled and can only be accessed using Private Endpoint - databricks_ui_api endpoint.
According to the Networking note of Microsoft-hosted agent,

You cannot use private connections such as ExpressRoute or VPN to connect Microsoft-hosted agents to your corporate network. The traffic between Microsoft-hosted agents and your servers will be over public network.

So, the Microsoft-hosted agents have no access to your Private Endpoint.
